# How to integrate grunt bootstrap less in a mean.io stack

Tags: gruntjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I want to build my own compiled css file
using the source Less bootstrap files
In my project I'm using the [mean.io](http://mean.io) stack.

how to integrate less in a mean stack ?

I found just a lot of tools out there
like

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bootstrap

https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-recess

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less

so I'm a little confused ^^

I'm also pleased with some tutorial

### UPDATE

I ended up using [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less)

copy by hand the file

*/less/bootstrap.less*
*/less/variables.less*

in my src folder ie
src/less

than in my grunt file

```
less: {
            bootstrap: {
                options: {
                    strictMath: true,
                    sourceMap: true,
                    outputSourceFiles: true,
                    sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
                    sourceMapFilename: '<%= distdir %>/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= distdir %>/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css': '<%= src.src %>/less/bootstrap.less'
                }
            }
        }
```

and in my variables.less I can do

```
//** Background color for `<body>`.
@body-bg:               #F70E29;
//** Global text color on `<body>`.
@text-color:            #F70E29;
```

and I've got the coolest bg body colors ever :)